# Join three tables with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have these three tables. I wrote my own SQL code but I can't convert it for `List<>`. Can you help me please?

SQL output:

[image]

And here is my SQL code:

```
Select 
    H.HastaAdSoyad, R.RandevuTarihi, R.RandevuSaati 
From 
    Hasta H 
Inner Join 
    Randevu R On H.HastaId = R.HastaId 
Inner Join 
    Doktor D On R.DoktorId = D.DoktorId
```

These are my tables:

[image]

Comment: @CodeNotFound thanks for edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **navigation properties** in your model. That means you don't need to worry about joins - they will be generated for you.

The equivalent LINQ query is simple as that:

```
var query = from hasta in db.Hasta
            select new
            { 
               hasta.HastaAdSoyad,
               hasta.Randevu.RandevuTarihi,
               hasta.Randevu.RandevuSaati
             };
var result = query.ToList();
```

It's not clear why the original SQL query includes join to `Doktor` table.

If you really want joins (for some unknown reason), then the query is

```
var query = from hasta in db.Hasta
            join randevu in db.Randevu on hasta.RandevuId equals randevu.RandevuId
            join doktor in db.Doktor on randevu.DoktorId equals doktor.DoktorId
            select new
            { 
               hasta.HastaAdSoyad,
               randevu.RandevuTarihi,
               randevu.RandevuSaati
             };
```

Comment: I need to join `Doktor` table cause DoktorId need to be equals of my session value.